# High order equation Solving

Tags: matlab, math, equation, raytracing

I am doing ray tracing and I have to make intersection between the ray and polynomial so I got the following equation and I have to solve it for t.

**A(21).*(Y.^5) + (A(20).*(Y.^4)).*X + A(19).*(Y.^4) + (A(18).*(Y.^3)).*(X.^2) + (A(17).*(Y.^3)).*X + A(16).*(Y.^3) + (A(15).*(Y.^2)).*(X.^3) + (A(14).*(Y.^2)).*(X.^2) + (A(13).*(Y.^2)).*X + A(12).*(Y.^2) + (A(11).*(Y)).*(X.^4) + (A(10).*Y).*(X.^3) + (A(9).*Y).*(X.^2) + (A(8).*Y).*(X) + (A(7).*Y) + A(6).*(X.^5) + A(5).*(X.^4) + A(4).*(X.^3) + A(3).*(X.^2) + A(2).*X + A(1) - Z = 0;**

While:

```
X = (px +t*dx);
Y = (py +t*dy);
Z = (pz +t*dz);
```

so I want to get t in respect to the other variables. ( I have all the other variables but I don't know how to calculate it )

I wanted to use `Solve` Function and that's what I did with an example to test it:
But I didn't get the answer

syms t px py pz dx dy dz A21 A20 A19 A18 A17 A16 A15 A14 A13 A12 A11 A10 A10 A9 A8 A7 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1;

solve(A21.*((py +t*dy).^5) + (A20.*((py +t*dy).^4)).*(px +t*dx) + A19.*((py +t*dy).^4) + (A18.*((py +t*dy).^3)).*((px +t*dx).^2) + (A17.*((py +t*dy).^3)).*(px +t*dx) + A16.*((py +t*dy).^3) + (A15.*((py +t*dy).^2)).*((px +t*dx).^3) + (A14.*((py +t*dy).^2)).*((px +t*dx).^2) + (A13.*((py +t*dy).^2)).*(px +t*dx) + A12.*((py +t*dy).^2) + (A11.*((py +t*dy))).*((px +t*dx).^4) + (A10.*(py +t*dy)).*((px +t*dx).^3) + (A9.*(py +t*dy)).*((px +t*dx).^2) + (A8.*(py +t*dy)).*((px +t*dx)) + (A7.*(py +t*dy)) + A6.*((px +t*dx).^5) + A5.*((px +t*dx).^4) + A4.*((px +t*dx).^3) + A3.*((px +t*dx).^2) + A2.*(px +t*dx) + A1 - (pz +t*dz),t)

Please support
Many thanks in advance

Comment: you probably should ask this question on the Mathematics site

Comment: I want to do it using matlab and I thing Solve function could help me. I tried it but I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong

Comment: @Jack_111 What makes you think that you are doing something wrong? Do you get an error or simply not the expected result? If you get an error which one, and if not, what do you get and what do you expect. Also, are you able to use the solve function to solve a simple equation?

Comment: Yes I got an error. I am doing that to get "t" but it said 

"Undefined function or variable 't'."

Comment: Note that substitutiong your variables X, Y and Z should work but is not required.

Comment: You are trying to get an analytical expression for t in the above case for an equation where t appears in quite high orders. That is rather difficult (impossible). Usually such equations are solved numerically. In this case you have to replace all your parameters with numbers (except t) and then find the zeros of the new equation.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with your attempt:

1. symbolic variables: Solve is part of the symbolic toolbox and you don't seem to declare your variables as symbolic anywhere
2. Equality operator: In matlab `=` stands for assignment, whilst `==` stands for equality
3. Role of `t`: You don't declare `t` beforehand, nor do you tell the solver to consider it a variable that can be solved for

Make sure to try some examples that are suggested when you run `doc solve`

Comment: I don't know what's happening. Please have a look on the edited question

Comment: The answer is RootOf and I can't fine the Root of the polynomial (Same problem)

Comment: @Jack_111 Your answer only contains half of an equation. Perhaps try adding `==0` before the comma. If that does not work try a tiny example first like I recommended and work up from there.